# Render correct partial In Rails w/AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to show all my posts on my home/index.html.erb page. I have a form to create a new post, but when I hit submit, the AJAX request goes off fine, but the response is blank

this is my posts/create.js.erb

```
$('#all-posts').html(" <%= j (render @posts) %> ");
$('#post-form').slideUp(350);
```

But the response is this in chrome dev tools

```
$('#all-posts').html(" ");
$('#post-form').slideUp(350);
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :all_posts, only: [:index, :create]
    respond_to :html, :js

    def new
        @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.create(post_params)
    end

    def edit
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.update_attributes(post_params)
    end

    def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
    end

    private

    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:content)
    end

    def all_posts
        @posts = Post.all
    end
end
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

end
```

This is where I want to display the post home/index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" id="all-posts">
          <%= render @posts %>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do your logs say?  I'd also consider just appending the newly created post rather than getting all the posts and re-rendering them

Comment: Can you show how you call your ajax?

Comment: '<%= simple_form_for @post, remote: true do |f|   %>'
   
' <%= f.input  :content, input_html: {class: 'form-group' } %>'

    '<%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn btn-success' %>'

'<% end %>'

Comment: I tried appending code instead of rendering @posts and its telling me everything is nil except the post.content. The id is nil, the user_id is nil so Apparently Im not creating it correctly I guess.

Comment: fixed the user part, but now I have different issues. I Need to look at this again